# When I register I cannot see the user name until I refresh or login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-reducers

when I register it take me to the dashboard page where there is a welcome note with user name but the issue is I cannot see the user name until I refresh or login again. I am sharing both my registration action.js code and my dashboard

> my registration.js code

```
const Register = (props) => {
const { classes } = props
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const onRegister = async () => {
    dispatch(startRegister(name, email, password));
    props.history.push('/dashboard')
}
```

> action.js

```
export const startRegister = (name, email, password) => {
    // const { name, email, password } = props
    return () => {
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((currentUser) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: name,
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log('Updated');

                    // Update successful.
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // An error happened.
                    console.log(error);
                });

                // history.push('/dashboard')
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage);
                // ..
            });
    };
};
```

> dashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = props => {
const { classes } = props
const onSignout = async (e) => {
    await firebase.auth().signOut()
    //props.history.push('/')
}
const username = useSelector(state => state.auth.name);

return (
    <main className={classes.main}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                {`Welcome User ${username ? username : ''}`}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance I belive the issue is because of javascript promises, firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword is an asynchronous function.

Try this

In **registration.js**

```
const onRegister = async () => {
    const userData = {name, email, password}
    dispatch(startRegister(props, userData));
}
```

In **action.js**

```
export const startRegister = (props, userData) => {
    const { name, email, password } = userData;
    return () => {
        return firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((currentUser) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: name,
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log('Updated');

                    // Navigate to dashboard after data is been saved
                    props.history.push('/dashboard');

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // An error happened.
                    console.log(error);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage);
                // ..
            });
        };
     };
```